# How to custom cancel button in laravel backpack?

Tags: laravel-backpack

First, here is my web looks like

[Web Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xoON.jpg)

I have this cancel button , i want to custom it so when i clicked it, it would redirect to another page.
Pls answer this thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is in the development stage for version 4.2 [issue lnk](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/3248).

But you can also add this feature by yourself. Publish your backpack library from the vendor folder. Create a file named cancel.blade.php in resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons and paste the below code.

```
@php
/*
    To override all cancel button urls with your custom url you should create a crud macro in your service provider
    We don't need to pass any parameter because there `$this` will be the crud panel.
*/
if($crud->hasMacro('cancelButtonUrl') && is_null($crud->getOperationSetting('cancelButtonUrl'))) {
    $cancel_button_href = $crud->cancelButtonUrl();
}else{
    //if developer provided a closure, run the closure.
    if(is_callable($crud->getOperationSetting('cancelButtonUrl'))) {
        $cancel_button_href = $crud->getOperationSetting('cancelButtonUrl')($crud);
    }else{
        //if nothing is specified about cancel button url we use the backpack defaults
        if(is_null($crud->getOperationSetting('cancelButtonUrl'))) {
            $cancel_button_href = $crud->hasAccess('list') ? url($crud->route) : url()->previous();
        }else{
            //developer might use a url string here if he does not need any customization in the closure.
            $cancel_button_href = $crud->getOperationSetting('cancelButtonUrl');
        }
    }
}
@endphp
@if(!$crud->hasOperationSetting('showCancelButton') || $crud->getOperationSetting('showCancelButton') == true)
<a href="{{ $cancel_button_href }}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="la la-ban"></span> &nbsp;{{ trans('backpack::crud.cancel') }}</a> 
@endif
```

create another file named form_save_buttons.blade.php in resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/inc directory and paste the below code.

```
@if(isset($saveAction['active']) && !is_null($saveAction['active']['value']))
<div id="saveActions" class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden" name="save_action" value="{{ $saveAction['active']['value'] }}">
    @if(!empty($saveAction['options']))
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            @endif

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <span class="la la-save" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp;
                <span data-value="{{ $saveAction['active']['value'] }}">{{ $saveAction['active']['label'] }}</span>
            </button>

            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                @if(!empty($saveAction['options']))
                    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">&#x25BC;</span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                        @foreach( $saveAction['options'] as $value => $label)
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="{{ $value }}">{{ $label }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>

                @endif
            </div>
            @if(!empty($saveAction['options']))
        </div>
    @endif

    @include('crud::buttons.cancel')
</div>
@endif
```

Now use this code in your crud controller to add a URL to the cancel button.

```
$this->crud->setOperationSetting(
        'cancelButtonUrl',
        function($crud) {
            return 'https://omg.com';
        },
        'create' //this can be ommited if you are adding in a specific operation
    );
```